# How to change the image in firefox/safari default tab

Tags: html, firefox, browser, safari

When you open a new tab in firefox mobile and safari there is a summary of most visited sites. Each site has an image, how can I change the image of my site that is shown there?

Example on safari/firefox:

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to change image to be the full width/height of the container? Instead of just a small box, and how to change the image in the box in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put different types of icons to the `<head>` part of your site. Something like this:

```html
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="57x57" href="apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="60x60" href="apple-touch-icon-60x60.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="120x120" href="apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="76x76" href="apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="152x152" href="apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-196x196.png" sizes="196x196" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-128.png" sizes="128x128" />
<meta name="application-name" content="&nbsp;"/>
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="mstile-144x144.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="mstile-70x70.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="mstile-150x150.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-wide310x150logo" content="mstile-310x150.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="mstile-310x310.png" />
```

There are services that help you generate different sizes of icons at once from one file. favicomatic.com, realfavicongenerator.net and others.

Comment: Yeah I know about favicons, are those what is shown in the default tab in both browsers?

Comment: Yes, bigger versions of them.